# Evaluate using cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

How can we evaluate this expression using  cauchy's integral formula $\int_C \frac{e^{\pi Z}}{ ( {Z^2 + 1})  ^2} dZ$ 
where $C$ is $|Z-i|=1$

Comment: Write the integrand in the form $$\frac{g(z)}{(z-i)^n},$$ where $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of the disk $\lvert z-i\rvert \leqslant 1$. A partial fraction decomposition of the denominator may prove helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly
$$
\int_{|z-i|=1} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{ ( {z^2 + 1})  ^2} dz=\int_{|z-i|=1} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\pi z}}{(z+i)^2}}{ ( {z-i})  ^2} dz.
$$

According to the Cauchy Integral formula $f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz$ we have for $a=i$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-i|=1} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\pi z}}{(z+i)^2}}{ ( {z-i})  ^2} dz
&=\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\pi z}}{(z+i)^2}\right)'_{z=i}=\left(\frac{\pi\mathrm{e}^{\pi z}}{(z+i)^2}-2\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\pi z}}{(z+i)^3}\right)_{z=i} \\ &=\frac{\pi\mathrm{e}^{\pi i}}{(i+i)^2}-2\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\pi i}}{(i+i)^3}=\frac{-\pi}{-4}-2\frac{-1}{-8i} =\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{i}{4}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\int_{|z-i|=1} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\pi z}}{(z+i)^2}}{ ( {z-i})  ^2} dz=\frac{\pi^2 i}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Comment: nice answer, more than enough

Comment: no need for partial fraction...